# MySQL Filter JSON_CONTAINS Any value from Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a JSON field in a MySQL database that contains values like `[1,3,4,7]`.  I would like to be able to easily supply another array from a PHP variable and determine if there is any overlap.  I know this example does not work, but this is what I am trying to do:

```
$DaysVar = $_GET['Days']; --Example is [1,5,8]

$sql = mysqli_query($db, "
    SELECT ScheduleID, 
           Days --Example is [1,3,4,7]
    FROM Schedule
    WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(Days, '$DaysVar')
");
```

How can I get this query to return a result since there is a 1 in each array?

Comment: please share table data

Comment: So you want only duplicated values in result? or counter of how many values are duplicated?

Comment: What version of Mysql are you in?

Comment: @JorgeCampos `JSON_CONTAINS` only available in 5.7.8 or later

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On MySQL 5.7.8+ you can perform a [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) for each separate value:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   Schedule 
WHERE  (   JSON_CONTAINS(Days, '1')
        OR JSON_CONTAINS(Days, '2')
        OR JSON_CONTAINS(Days, '6')
       )
```

When the values to be searched for are stored in a PHP variable -- as in your question -- then you could build the above SQL like this:

```php
$DaysVar = $_GET['Days'];
$condition = implode(" OR ", array_map(function($day) {
    return "JSON_CONTAINS(Days, '".intval($day)."')";
}, $DaysVar));
$sql = mysqli_query($db, "
    SELECT ScheduleID, 
           Days
    FROM   Schedule
    WHERE  ($condition)
");
```

To avoid SQL injection, you should better prepare your statement creating a string like with `substr(str_repeat(" OR JSON_CONTAINS(Days, ?)", count($DaysVar)), 3)` and then call `mysqli_prepare` on it, then bind, ...etc.

#### MySQL 8.*

Since MySQL 8 you can use [`JSON_OVERLAPS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-overlaps):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   Schedule
WHERE  JSON_OVERLAPS(Days, '$DaysVar')
```

Again, you would better prepare the statement (with a `?` placeholder), then bind `$DaysVar` to it, and finally execute it.

Comment: This won't help since the values will be dynamic.

Comment: Yeah. I have the same problem with dynamic count of JSON array elements. And I need mysql-only solution. How you fixed this?

Comment: Those queries are vulnerable to SQL injection! You need to sanitize day to an int or use prepared statements

Answer (score 2):

Probably you found a solution, but for those looking for an answer in the future:

There is now `JSON_OVERLAPS()`, which in your example you can just swap out for `JSON_CONTAINS()`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-overlaps

Answer (score 0):

Table :

[image: table details]

Sample Data:

[image]

In my case, I achieved it with below query if you want data in different row then remove `GROUP_CONCAT`

Query :

```
 SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(wis.wi) FROM profile_card_stacks,
 JSON_TABLE(work_industry, "$[*]" COLUMNS(wi INT PATH '$')) as wis
 where wis.wi in(10,14);
```