# JSON_SEARCH with a list / dynamic MySQL query in R

Tags: r, json

I do have a MySQL table called `user_activities` where one column (`activities`) is in JSON format:

```
id      name    activities
1       Peter   ["football", "volley"]
2       Mary    ["football", "hockey", "basketball"]
3       Jason   ["volley", "hockey", "golf"]
```

And I need to construct a query that, given a list of activities, will return all those users that have at least one of the activities in this list.

**Example 1**:

Given a list

```
inputList <- list("football", "basketball")
```

the MySQL query should return:

```
  id      name    activities
1       Peter   ["football", "volley"]
2       Mary    ["football", "hockey", "basketball"]
```

**Example 2**:

Given a list

```
inputList <- list("hockey", "golf", "basketball")
```

the MySQL query should return:

```
id      name    activities
2       Mary    ["football", "hockey", "basketball"]
3       Jason   ["volley", "hockey", "golf"]
```

I know that it's possible to check the existence of each element checking activity by activity, like:

```
 SELECT * FROM user_activities 
 WHERE JSON_SEARCH(`activities`, 'one', 'football') IS NOT NULL 
 OR JSON_SEARCH(`activities`, 'one', 'basketball') IS NOT NULL 
 OR JSON_SEARCH(`activities`, 'one', 'volley') IS NOT NULL 
 OR JSON_SEARCH(`activities`, 'one', 'hockey') IS NOT NULL 
 OR JSON_SEARCH(`activities`, 'one', 'golf') IS NOT NULL;
```

But if an activity it's not in the specified list (`inputList`), I don't want to check its existence in `activities`. And this `inputList` changes every time I run the MySQL query.

So, is there any way to just check the list with the content in `activities`? I tried with:

```
 SELECT * FROM user_activities
 WHERE JSON_SEARCH(`activities`, 'all', (",paste(shQuote(inputList, type = "sh"), collapse = ','),")) IS NOT NULL;
```

but it 'obviously' returns an error:

```
`Error in .local(conn, statement, ...): could not run statement: Operand should contain 1 column(s)`
```

because `JSON_SEARCH` checks if a single string exists in a json array or a json document, and I'm not putting a single string in the function.

And `JSON_CONTAINS`

```
SELECT * FROM user_activities
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`activities`->'$[*]', JSON_ARRAY(", paste(shQuote(inputList, type = "sh"), collapse = ','), "))
```

returns if all the elements in the `inputList` exist in `activities`, and I want if any of the elements exist in `activities` (not necessarily all).

How could I achieve this?

**Edit**

I found a solution (see answer below) by building a dynamic query as it is suggested in this question [MySQL Filter JSON_CONTAINS Any value from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247098/mysql-filter-json-contains-any-value-from-array) for PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself a solution with the dynamic query option I mentioned in the **Edit** part.

```
library(tractor.base)

condition <- function(dbcolumn,inlist){
   cond <- implode(sapply(inlist, function(x) paste0("JSON_SEARCH(`",dbcolumn,"`, 'one', '", x,"') IS NOT NULL")), " OR ")
return(cond)
}
```

So, if I call the function (with the Example 2 in my question):

```
condition("activities",inputList)
```

it returns:

```
"JSON_SEARCH(`activities`, 'one', 'hockey') IS NOT NULL OR JSON_SEARCH(`activities`, 'one', 'golf') IS NOT NULL OR JSON_SEARCH(`activities`, 'one', 'basketball') IS NOT NULL"
```

So the MySQL query in R will finally look like:

```
query <- paste0("SELECT * FROM user_activities 
                 WHERE ", condition("activities", inputList),";")
```