# Query builder filtering rows that have atleast one value from array in JSON column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel 8, I'm trying to make local scope filtering of users with JSON array columns in the related table. The problem is that I don't know how to check if the JSON column contains at least one value from the array I declared at the beginning.

```
public function scopeViewable($query)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $locations = $user->getShopAccess()->pluck('id')->toArray();
    if ($user->hasPermissionTo('users.index'))
    {
        return $query->whereHas('shopAccess', function (Builder $q) {
           // return $q->whereJsonContains('location_ids', "");
           // Here is the problem I want to check if location_ids contain at least one value 
           // from $locations
        });
    }
}
```

Example of values that are contained in column location_ids is
`["1", "2", "5"]` , integer values wrapped as string

`$locations` variable is an array of integer values.

If it is possible to check if the `location_ids` column is a subset of `$locations`, that would be great.

Comment: Can you give an example of the value contained in the `location_ids` column?

Comment: ["1", "2", "5"] - This is the example of location_ids column, and on the other hand, the $locations are array of ids that were extracted from collection of models.

Answer (score 0):

According to this question
[MySQL Filter JSON_CONTAINS Any value from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247098/mysql-filter-json-contains-any-value-from-array)

You have 2 options. Use json_contains for each element of the array or use the newer json_overlaps function if your mysql has access to it.

```php
return $query->whereHas('shopAccess', function (Builder $q) use ($locations) {
    $q->where(function ($where) use ($locations) {
        foreach ($locations as $location) {
            $q->orWhereJsonContains('location_ids', $location);
        }
    });
});
```

```php
$locations = $user->getShopAccess()->pluck('id')->values();

return $query->whereHas('shopAccess', function (Builder $q) use ($locations) {
    $q->whereRaw('JSON_OVERLAPS(location_ids, ?)', [$locations->toJson()]);
});
```