# Is there any performant way to run a JSON_CONTAINS query in mysql 5.7 on multiple values

Tags: mysql-5.7

I have an array of objects inside a mysql json column, and I'd like to query all rows where one of these objects contains a member within a list of values.

continuing from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247098/mysql-filter-json-contains-any-value-from-array)

```
SELECT * 
FROM   sometable 
WHERE  (   JSON_CONTAINS(json, JSON_OBJECT('id', '1'), '$') 
        OR JSON_CONTAINS(json, JSON_OBJECT('id', '2'), '$') 
        OR JSON_CONTAINS(json, JSON_OBJECT('id', '3'), '$') 
       )
```

is 3 times as slow as doing three queries. Is there a more performant approach?

Comment: No.  IMHO the best to you always.

Answer (score 0):

You can gain some time by directly targeting property as comparing objects is way more longer because Mysql have to parse both :

```sql
SELECT * FROM sometable
WHERE  (   JSON_CONTAINS(jsondata, '1', '$.id') 
        OR JSON_CONTAINS(jsondata, '2', '$.id') 
        OR JSON_CONTAINS(jsondata, '3', '$.id') 
       );
```

You can also use a more concise way with `IN` operator and [JSON_EXTRACT shortcut](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path) :

```sql
SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE jsondata->"$.id" IN (1,2,3)
```

I've made a [quick fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fYFp5Sny4p4ypuY3E2iUzW/4) to illustrate and it seems to be twice as fast on average (db-fiddle is not always consistent in processing time)

Anyway, searching a non indexed column in Mysql will always be a pain. If you can, you may consider using a [generated column from your json](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html#json-column-indirect-index) that can be indexed.

I've made an [other fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/myQpKxccXKBiAfAhYpm7pr/0) you can check.